# for loop stuck and not interating (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, increment

I'm currently working on a small script that aims to find taxicab numbers. There is only one small problem, the for loop doesn't increment the variable x and is stuck looping forever. I'll paste the relevant part of the code below:

```
n = int(10)
counter = int(0)
m = int(m)
x = int(1)
y = int(n**(1/3))
cheatsheet = []

while counter in range(0,m):
    for x in range(1,y):
        if x**3 + y**3 < n:
            print('less than')
            print(x,y,n)
            continue
        elif x**3 + y**3 > n:
            print('greater than')
            y -= 1
            continue
        elif x > y:
            if n in cheatsheet:
                print('counting')
                counter = counter+1
                #checking if n occurs in the list, if so it will add 1 to the counter so that the program will know when to stop
            n = n + 1
            y = int(n**(1/3))
            x = 1
            print('break1')
            #resetting values and bumping n so that it will continue the quest to find 'em all
            break
        else:
            if x and y == 1:
                #this is an error correction for low n values, i mean really low it might be redundant by now
                n = n + 1
                y = int(n**(1/3))
                x = 1
                print('break2')
                break
            cheatsheet.append((n,x,y))        
print(cheatsheet)
```

This yields the following result in a terminal window:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xNZw.png)

Note that I killed the process by myself, the program did not.
As you can tell, the script just loops around and prints 'less than' and the values for x,y,n.

Help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: the variable m is given by the user, but not included in this bit of code.

Comment: I think your for loop is working fine, but your while loop is not being cancelled. The continue statement gets the program out of the for loop, but the counter for your while loop is never updated.

Comment: If you look at the image I've uploaded, it won't bump x=1 to x=2. Hence it is stuck.

Comment: range(1,2) means it will iterate just 1. its an exclusive endpoint. Meaning: if you do 
for x in range(1,3):
    print(x)
you get 
1
2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has a number of issues wrong with it I'm not willing to post functional code but I will point some of the issues out.

For starters:

```
n = int(10)
```

isn't required, not an error but redundant. Use `n = 10` with the same effect.

Then:

```
while counter in range(0,m):
```

will always evaluate to `True`. `m` is *never modified so the membership test always succeeds, maybe you need to re-evaluate your looping.

```
for x in range(1,y):
```

This will assign `x` the value `1` all the time. `y` evaluates to `2` by your arithmetic (int rounds floats to the floor, i.e `int(2.9) -> 2`) so either use `math.ceil` or add one to your `y`.

Appart from that you re-assign variable names all the time inside your loops, that's confusing and might lead to unexpected behavior.